# imageView with layout_weight attribute and src fail to fit the given Size

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-layout-weight

When i try to have an ImageView inside a LinearLayout with layout_weight and an image, the ImageView takes over the entire space.

Lets say i have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/red"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/green"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout (onscreen) looks like this:

**(Not enough Reputation to post images, sorry)**

////////

BLUE LinearLayout (1/10 of the Main layout)

////////

RED ImageView (8/10 of the Main layout)

////////

Green LinearLayout (1/10 of the Main layout)

////////

---

but if i add an image(large one...) to the ImageView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/green"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

it looks like this:

////////

RED ImageView (10/10 of the Main layout) - with the image.....

////////

anyone knows how can i make the src of the ImageView fit into the given space(8/10 of the main LinearLayout)
Thanks.

Comment: try using scaleType fitXY

Comment: doesn't work, no matter what scaleType i choose....

Comment: Use xml bitmap drawables.

Comment: please explain? the image inside the ImageView will be downloaded from a server and not a resource in my package

Answer (score 1):

apparently it is an issue with android studio preview (before android API level 19)

when deploying to a device it works perfect....